# why I am getting this error Unknown provider in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I trying to do a simple application that displays the list of products in a table.
I am using angularJS v1.4 in a Spring boot application.

produitService.js:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.service('serviceProduit', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    this.getProduits = function() {
        return $resource("http://localhost:8080/produits",null,{'get':{method:'GET'}});
    }
}]);
```

produitController.js:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller(
    'produitController', [ '$scope', '$rootScope', 'serviceProduit',
        function($scope, $rootScope, serviceProduit) {
            $scope.getProduits = function() {
                serviceProduit.getProduits().get().$promise
                    .then(function(response) {
                        $scope.produits = response.result;
                        console.log(response);
                    }, function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
            };
            $scope.getProducts ();
        } ]);
```

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="produitController">
    <div class="container">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Designation</th>
                <th>Prix</th>
                <th>Quantite</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="p in produits">
                <td>{{p.id}}</td>
                <td>{{p.designation}}</td>
                <td>{{p.prix}}</td>
                <td>{{p.quantite}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="functions/services/produitService.js"></script>
    <script src="functions/controllers/produitController.js"></script>
</body>
```

When I inspect the browser console, I am getting this error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: serviceProduitProvider <-
>   serviceProduit <- produitController
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=serviceProduitProvider%20%3C-%20serviceProduit%20%3C-%20produitController
>       at angular.js:68
>       at angular.js:4289
>       at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4437)
>       at angular.js:4294
>       at getService (angular.js:4437)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:4469)
>       at extend.instance (angular.js:9136)
>       at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8248)
>       at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7680)
>       at publicLinkFn (angular.js:7555)

How to solve **Unknown provider error**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove declaring the module again in the produitController.js ,

```
//remove this line var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller(
    'produitController', [ '$scope', '$rootScope', 'serviceProduit',
        function($scope, $rootScope, serviceProduit) {
```

Also you need to inject ngResource to your app since you are using $resource

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource']);
app.service('serviceProduit', ['$resource', function($resource) {
```

make sure to add the reference in your html too

Comment: now I am getting this error: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngResource due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngResource' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Comment: did you add the reference to the index?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add this line `<script src = "bower_components / angular-resource / angular-resource.js"></ script>` now there is no errors but my table **is empty**, I checked my database and it contains data. Also, I checked the url, it displays a result like this: `[{"id":1,"designation":"HP 678","prix":900.0,"quantite":6},{"id":2,"designation":"Samsung Galaxy","prix":960.0,"quantite":5}]`

Comment: anyhow what do yo see when you do this console.log($scope.produits);

Comment: I have nothing in the console. the `console.log(response);` does not display anything.

Comment: I forgot to call the controller function. I just added this line: `$scope.getProducts ();` in the controller after the function declaration. now everything works well. ty for your help. I updated the code.